# Chess movie as educational incentive

Tags: teaching

I am trying to encourage a young friend to learn chess. He is very interested, just like any child would be with a child's play. I am wondering which movie about chess to choose, that could cause more interest and improved learning to him.

Comment: maybe "searching for bobby fischer."

Answer (score 5):

Searching for Bobby Fisher maybe.
Trailer: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8khmNiamBxo

http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0108065/

Answer (score 1):

In addition to great suggestion by Mark.
You can also try Brooklyn Castle: http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1800266/

It seems quite inspirational, the main message 'it's also cool to play chess'.

Answer (score 1):

First movie that came to my mind was [Life of a King](http://www.rottentomatoes.com/m/life_of_a_king_2013/), but some scenes are not recommended to young children. You should watch it before and then decide yourself!

Maybe you can also check out [Algorithms](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt2616594/?ref_=ttpl_pl_tt). I didn't manage to see it, but seems to be quite inspirational.

Answer (score 1):

- Queen of Katwe [1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Queen_of_Katwe)
- Lang Leve de Koningin (i guess only available in dutch and german?) [2](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lang_lebe_die_K%C3%B6nigin)

Answer (score 1):

A movie that I like about chess is "[The Luzhin Defense](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Luzhin_Defence)".

However, the movie might encourage your friend not to be obsessive with chess. Anyhow, the tactical problems showed in the movie deserves a view if you are yet a chess player.